# Right-align text

Tags: code-golf, string

Your job is to take a string input and a number and align the string to the right, making the width of the text the number. When a line is too long, break it and put the rest on the next line, repeating until it's not necessary. If a line is shorter than the width, then pad it with spaces. Multiple newlines can occur, and should be treated like any other single character.

For example, the string

```
Programming
Puzzles
&
Code
Golf
```

and the number `5` would produce:

```
Progr
ammin
    g
Puzzl
   es
    &
 Code
 Golf
```

Whereas the same string and the number `10` would produce:

```
Programmin
         g
   Puzzles
         &
      Code
      Golf
```

The string

```
a

b
```

and the number 5 would produce:

```
    a
      <-- note the 5 spaces
    b
```

Shortest code wins!

Comment: The text says “Break the lines *when necessary* [...]”, but your examples suggest that you break after *every* word, even when it would fit. Please clarify: do we place each word on a new line, or do we implement an actual word-wrapping algorithm?

Comment: Can there be spaces in the middle of an input line, e.g. `Programming Puzzles\n&\nCode Golf`?

Comment: @sp3000 There can be any character, including spaces.

Comment: @Timwi: The example has one word per line.  It would have been better to include some multi-word lines to make it clear that space within a line isn't special.  (i.e. there are only newlines, and non-newlines.)

Comment: Do 5 char take 1 or 2 lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
jm.[\ QdscRQ.z
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm.%5B%5C+QdscRQ.z&input=5%0AProgramming%0APuzzles%0A%26%0ACode%0AGolf&debug=0)

Uses Pyth's pad operator.

Answer (score 10):

### Python 2, 84

```python
s,n=input()
for w in s.split('\n'):
 w=w or' '
 while w:print w[:n].rjust(n);w=w[n:]
```

Takes as input a string with newlines and a number, and prints the result. For each line in the input, takes and prints `n` chars at a time, using the built-in `rjust` to pad the left with spaces before printing.

I fixed the empty line case with the hack `w=w or' '`. There's probably a better method but I'm not going to think much about it.

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, 21 bytes

```
li_qN/Sfe|f/ff{\Se[N}
```

*Thanks to @Sp3000 for golfing off 1 byte and paving the way for 3 more.*

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=li_qN%2FSfe%7Cf%2Fff%7B%5CSe%5BN%7D&input=5%0AProgramming%0APuzzles%0A%0A%26%0A%0ACode%0AGolf).

#### How it works

```
li                     Read an integer L from the first line of input.
  _                    Push a copy.
   qN/                 Split the remaining input at linefeeds.
      Sfe|             Map `OR " "'; the replaces empty lines with a space.
          f/           Split each line into chunks of length L.
            ff{     }  For each chunk, push L and the chunk; then:
               \         Swap L with the chunk.
                Se[      Left-pad the chunk to length L by prepending " ".
                   N     Push a linefeed.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 16

```
jm>Q+*\ QdscRQ.z
```

[Try it online here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%3EQ%2B%2a%5C+QdscRQ.z&input=5%0AProgramming%0APuzzles%0A%26%0ACode%0AGolf&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
jm>Q+*\ QdscRQ.z             : Q is the number on the first line, .z takes the rest
           cRQ.z             : chop each line of .z into chunks of Q characters
 m        s                  : remove nested lists and map over the result
    +*\ Qd                   : add Q spaces to each line d
  >Q                         : take the last Q characters of that result
j                            : join results on newlines
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 39 bytes

```
perl -ni5 -e 's!^$|.{1,$^I}!printf"%${^I}s
",$&!ge'
```

36 bytes + 3 bytes for `-ni`. The wrap width is passed as the argument to `-i`.

Handles blank lines properly by padding them with spaces:

```
$ echo -e "Programming\nPuzzles\n\n&\n\nCode\nGolf" | perl -ni5 -e 's!^$|.{1,$^I}!printf"%${^I}s
",$&!ge'
Progr
ammin
    g
Puzzl
   es

    &

 Code
 Golf
```

### How it works

This solution uses the substitution operator to loop through the input, saving a byte over the equivalent `for` loop. The real trick, though, is in the regex on the LHS of the substitution:

```
^$|.{1,$^I}
```

With the global modifier, this will match `$^I` characters at a time; when there are less than `$^I` characters remaining in the string, it will match everything to the end. The alternation with `^$` is required to handle blank lines. For example:

```
$ echo -e "foo\n\nbar" | perl -ni2 -E 'say "<$_>" for /^$|.{1,$^I}/g'
<fo>
<o>
<>
<ba>
<r>
```

The RHS of the substitution simply uses `printf` to left-pad the matched chunk with spaces.

Comment: I always forget about `$^I`!

Comment: @DomHastings I learned that trick from chilemagic, who mentioned it in a [comment on another challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55880/find-the-occurrences-of-a-character-in-an-input-string/55890#comment137278_55890).

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (ES6), 107

I wish JS had a built in pad function. Oh well.

```js
(a,b)=>a.replace(eval(`/(.{${b}})(?!\\n)/g`),`$1
`).split`
`.map(c=>(Array(b).join` `+c).slice(-b)).join`
`
```

Explanation:

```js
(a, b)=>

  // searches for sequences of characters longer than b without a newline after them and
  // adds a newline after every b characters of the sequence
  a.replace(eval(`/(.{${b}})(?!\\n)/g`), '$1\n')
    .split('\n')
    .map(c=>

      // prepends b spaces to each string then slices it from the right down to length b
      ( Array(b).join(' ') + c ).slice(-b)

    ).join('\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 126 bytes

```julia
f(s,n)=for i=split(s,"\n") while length(i)>0 println(lpad(i[1:min(n,end)],n));length(i)<n?break:(i=i[min(n+1,end):end])end;end
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(s::String, n::Int)
    for i in split(s, "\n")
        while length(i) > 0
            println(lpad(i[1:min(n,end)], n))
            length(i) < n ? break : (i = i[min(n+1,end):end])
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

### Bash, <strike>62</strike>, <strike>61</strike>+feature, 59

Shorter if `N` can be set by the caller, instead of having to read it as the first line of input.

```
# width as a function arg: 59 chars
f()while read -rn$1 r;do [[ $r ]]&&printf %$1s\\n "$r";done
# width on stdin: 64 chars  (not updated with later suggestions&ideas)
read N;while read -rn$N r;do [[ $r ]]&&printf %$N's\n' "$r";done
```

This fails to handle empty lines in the input.  Otherwise, this doesn't subject the input data to word-splitting, pathname expansion, or otherwise treat it as more than just raw data.

`read -n$N` saves one character, but lets `read` munge `\`.

The `[[ $r ]]&&` is needed because `read -n4` can't lookahead to see that the next char is a newline.  So it sets `r` to a 4-char string, and the next read produces a zero-char empty string.  Filtering these false newlines without filtering real newlines would require tracking state: whether the previous line was max-length or not.  Either more code or a totally different approach would be needed.

`[[ $r ]]` is shorter than `[ -n "$r" ]` which is needed to avoid errors if the line starts with `-z foo`, or is `*` or something, if you used `[ $r ]`.

Justication happens with the standard printf "%4s" format string.

Test with

```
f()(while read -rn$1 r;do [[ $r ]]&&printf %$1s\\n "$r";done); (echo 4; echo -e "*\n\\"; cat /tmp/lines) | f 4
```

Comment: 1. I'd include `-r` in the byte count. 2. `f()(while ... done)` is a bit shorter.

Comment: @Dennis: Without `[[ $r ]]&&`, if N=4, an input line of length 4 will produce a blank output line where there wasn't one before.  Because `read` returns a string of 4 chars, *then* sees a newline on the next call and returns right away.  Also, thanks for the `()` tip.  I didn't know you could define fns that way.

Comment: I recommend reading [Tips for golfing in Bash](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15279). It's a great resource.

Comment: Actually, since `while` is already compound, you don't even need the parentheses: `f()while ... done`

Comment: @Dennis: wow, haxx.  Thanks for the link.  A couple of those things were new to me, and I fixed a couple things in another answer :)  I don't normally golf, but >15 years of being a command-line junkie has taught me a thing or two :)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 108 bytes

```
import Data.List.Split
k[]=[""]
k x=x
f n=unlines.(map(\l->([1..n-length l]>>" ")++l).k.chunksOf n=<<).lines
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> putStr $ f 5 "a\n\nb\ncd\nMatamorphosis"
    a

    b
   cd
Matam
orpho
  sis
```

How it works

```
                              .lines   -- split input string at newlines
                           =<<         -- for every line
                  chunksOf n           --    split into chunks of length n
                k                      --    fix empty lines
    map                                --    for every chunk
        \l->([1..n-length l]>>" "      --      make a string of missing spaces
                        ++l            --      and append the chunk
unlines                                -- join padded chunks with newlines in-between
```

Answer (score 1):

### GNU awk + bash, 70

```
f()(awk -vFPAT=.\{,$1} '{for(i=0;i++<NF;){printf "%'$1's\n",$i}}/^$/')
```

Using bash to slot the count into the awk program is prob. smaller than reading it with a `NR==1{N=$0}` block.

Read a line at a time.  Split into at-most-4 character chunks, using FPAT.  (matches the fields, rather than the separators. GNU extension.)  printf each field separately.  (Default ORS = \n).

The `/^$/` rule is there to print empty lines, which have NF=0 and thus don't print at all in the other block.  So unlike my pure-bash solution, this actually works in the general case.

Semi-unrelated, but my idea so far for perl is 112 chars for just the perl code:

```
(echo 4; echo -e 'foo\nbar'; echo -e "*\n\\"; echo '~$(true)'; cat /tmp/lines) |  # test input
perl -e '$N=<>;$/=\1;print "$N\n"; while(<>){if(/\n/ or length($l)>=$N){printf("%$4s\n",$l);$l=/\n/?"":$_;}else{$l.=$_;}}'
```

This eats one of the newlines, and is way too long.  `$/=\1` reads a byte at a time.  We append to $l.  Probably a line-at-a-time with fixed-width split approach would be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + GNU utils, 41

```
fold -$1|sed ":;s/^.\{,$[$1-1]\}\$/ &/;t"
```

String is input via STDIN, width is input by command-line arg:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo 'Programming
Puzzles
&
Code
Golf'|./ralign.sh 10
Programmin
         g
   Puzzles
         &
      Code
      Golf
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 151 bytes

```
s,n=input();N='\n'
for w in[i.lstrip()if i.replace(' ','').isalpha()else i for i in s.replace(N,'\n ').split(N)]:
 while w:print w[:n].rjust(n);w=w[n:]
```

This is a adaptation of @xnor's answer above, as his does not properly handle newlines.

---

The `for` loop was changed from:

```
for w in s.split('\n'):
```

to:

```
for w in[i.lstrip()if i.replace(' ','').isalpha()else i for i in s.replace(N,'\n ').split(N)]:
```

---

## Example

```
$ python main.py
"Programming\n\n\nPuzzles\n\n&\n\nCode\nGolf", 5
Progr
ammin
    g


Puzzl
   es

    &

 Code
 Golf
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 143 bytes

```
(s,n)=>Join("\n",s.Split('\n').SelectMany(l=>(l.Any()?l:" ").Select((c,i)=>new{c,i}).GroupBy(o=>o.i/n,o=>o.c).Select(g=>Concat(g).PadLeft(n))))
```

Linq lets you make pretty gnarly expressions. `GroupBy` is useful here, but it's a shame they couldn't create function overloads taking the index.

Assign the lambda to a `Func<string, int, string>` to run it

Less golfed:

```
Func<string, int, string> Align = (s, n) => Join("\n", 
    s.Split('\n')
     .SelectMany(l => (l.Any() ? l : " ")
         .Select((c, i) => new { c, i })
         .GroupBy(o => o.i / n, o => o.c)
         .Select(g => Concat(g).PadLeft(n))));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque, 28 Bytes

Same as the version below, but treats line 1 as the number and
the other lines as the string.

```
lng_riPpun{pPco{pP' lp}mu}Wl
```

Usage as in:

```
$ cat input.txt | blsq --stdin "lng_riPpun{pPco{pP' lp}mu}Wl"
Progr
ammin
    g
Puzzl
   es
    &
 Code
 Golf
```

Old Version (16 bytes):

```
{5co{5' lp}mu}Wl
```

Example:

```
blsq ) "Programming\nPuzzles\n&\nCode\nGolf"{5co{5' lp}mu}Wl
Progr
ammin
    g
Puzzl
   es
    &
 Code
 Golf
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 63 bytes

Returns the correctly alligned string. Didn't know there was a padLeft (and padRight, padCenter) function until now.

```
f={s,n->s.split("(?<=\\G.{$n})|\n")*.padLeft(n," ").join("\n")}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript <del>174</del> 136

```
function R(s,x){return s.replace(new RegExp(".{"+x+"}","g"),"$&\n").replace(/[^\n]*/g,function(m){
while(m.length<x)m=" "+m;return m;})}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ceylon, 107

```
String w(String s,Integer n)=>"\n".join{for(l in s.lines)for(p in l.partition(n))String(p).padLeading(n)};
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, 99 bytes

Thanks to @beaker for removing 6 bytes!

Using and anonymous function:

```
@(s,k)fliplr(char(cellfun(@fliplr,strsplit(regexprep(s,sprintf('\\S{%i}',k),'$0\n'),'\n'),'un',0)))
```

Define the function and use `ans` to call it:

```
>> @(s,k)fliplr(char(cellfun(@fliplr,strsplit(regexprep(s,sprintf('\\S{%i}',k),'$0\n'),'\n'),'un',0)))

ans =

@(s,k)fliplr(char(cellfun(@fliplr,strsplit(regexprep(s,sprintf('\\S{%i}',k),'$0\n'),'\n'),'un',0)))

>> ans(['Programming' 10 'Puzzles' 10 '&' 10 'Code' 10 'Golf'], 5) %% 10 is line feed

ans =

Progr
ammin
    g
Puzzl
   es
    &
 Code
 Golf
```