# Javascript left-pad golf

Tags: code-golf, string

#### Introduction

In the wake of the [left-pad npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/left-pad) [fallout](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4bjss2/an_11_line_npm_package_called_leftpad_with_only/), let's have a code golf for implementing left-pad.

The *left-pad* function consists of 2 default arguments and 1 additional argument, in the form **string**, **length**, (**padchar**). If the padchar is not given, this is **standardized** to a *space character*. Let's take an example with two arguments:

```
left_pad("abc", 6)
```

First, we observe the length of the string, which is **3**. After this, we need to pad this string in the left until the length of the full string has reached the length given in the function. In this case **6**. Since the padchar is *not given*, we need to pad this with spaces:

```
   abc
```

This is a string with 3 spaces and the initial string, resulting into a string with length 6. Here is an example with the padchar given:

```
left_pad("abc", 6, "-")
```

We just do the same as the example above, but replace the spaces with the padchar. In this case, the hyphen:

```
---abc
```

#### The Task

Given the **string**, **length**, and *maybe* the additional argument **padchar**, output the left-padded string. You can assume that the length number is equal or greater than the length of the string. The padchar will always consist of 1 character.

#### Test cases

```
left_pad("string", length, ("padchar")) === "left-padded string"

left_pad("foo", 5) === "  foo"
left_pad("foobar", 6) === "foobar"
left_pad("1", 2, "0") === "01"
left_pad("1", 2, "-") === "-1"
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the smallest number of bytes wins!

Comment: Also, in the future, I'd recommend posting in the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get feedback before you challenge is live, and note that restricting to a language is highly discouraged, since it limits participation.

Comment: @m0sa It would be valid, but I'd find it too straightforward to be interesting.  There's already a challenge to [right-align text](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58549/right-align-text), which basically requires padding as a sub-task.

Comment: @m0sa There's still a few issues. Restricting the challenge to javascript is strongly discouraged -- there's no reason other languages can't participate in this. The spec should describe the desired behavior and range of possible allowed inputs without needing to follow a link. It's not clear offhand how the third parameter is being handled.

Comment: I am certain that a Javascript-relevant reference can be made for motivation, without having to say "therefore no other languages are allowed to play". If you are particularly interested in seeing the best Javascript entries you could offer a bounty for it, while still leaving the challenge open for other languages.

Comment: Either single language questions are forbidden or they aren't. If they are forbidden, close this. If they are allowed, let the OP restrict the question as they like.

Comment: @Sklivvz Single language is allowed, though I may venture to say it's the reason the downvotes are pouring in now. We should discuss though banning it in the future, since it's existence seems like a trap.

Comment: @xnor thanks, that's what I meant. As an outsider, this feels like a bad community reaction to a valid question :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz A challenge we have in the SE question-answer framework is that the SE rules are designed to separate on-topic questions from off-topic ones, but in a site whose goal is competition and entertainment, there's a large grey area of things that are not against the rules, but are generally believed to make for a less interesting challenge. Feel free to join chat and discuss more.

Comment: @xnor looks like the entertainment ship has already sailed, otherwise this would've been [tag:popularity-contest]

Comment: @Sklivvz (and m0sa) There are rare cases where language-specific challenges make sense, particularly if the challenge requires some very unique feature of a language to make sense or even be a challenge in the first place. That's the main reason those are allowed and why I'd also be opposed to disallowing them completely. That said, for any challenge that *does* make sense in any language, there's no good reason to restrict it to one language. Otherwise, we'd have "Sort an array in JavaScript", "Sort an array in Ruby", "Sort an array in Python"... and 300 more challenges for no benefit at all.

Comment: @MartinBüttner the challenge was intended in "replace the left-pad" npm dependency. I don't oppose other languages but they should interface with js and pass the tests?

Comment: @Sklivvz As trichoplax said, this is a fine motivation for a challenge, but it boils down to a very simple string-processing task that makes just as much sense in any other language. The challenge is not specifically hard, doable or interesting in JavaScript compared to any other language (in particular, someone might not have known about the left-pad package, and still ask this question without the language restriction, and the answers in JavaScript wouldn't have been affected at all, and neither would anyone have thought "why isn't this JS-only?").

Comment: In c# one can answer `s.PadLeft(n,p);`...

Comment: @Sklivvz It's common practice to disallow built-ins that exactly implement what the challenge asks if that's a concern.

Comment: Nah, my only concern is that the OP wanted (with reason) creative javascript answers, but the only way to make this work here is to allow any language, disallow built ins, ask for code golf. It ended up being a completely different, non-fun, question. Probably it was the wrong site for it.

Comment: This really shouldn't have [tag:javascript]. The JavaScript in the title is fine for the relevance, though.

Comment: @tac Why is that? As long as the challenge has the language restriction, I think the tag is fine.

Comment: @MartinBüttner It's not like anyone's going to obey the language restriction when it has no reason to exist.

Comment: @tac I think the "Not an answer" flag exists for this reason.

Comment: @Mystagogue You're gonna waste mods' time by flagging answers in the "wrong" language? There are no language rules on this site, the only reason some challenges are "restricted" to certain languages is because they wouldn't make any sense otherwise. This challenge is clearly undertakable by many languages, and there's no justification for such a restriction.

Comment: @tac All four test cases already appear to be in the question.

Comment: @Mystagogue I hadn't bothered clicking the link but I kinda assumed there were more.

Comment: @edc65 I didn't make up the test cases up by myself,  so I don't want to make them more detailed or anything.  I guess we could add bonus points to implementations that behave weird in unspecified edge cases?

Comment: @Sklivvz, m0sa: re: entertainment value, yes, it's true that part of the purpose of this site can be to have fun. That's not an excuse for posting an off-topic or otherwise prohibited form of challenge. "Fun" does not mean "anything goes;" just like all other Stack Exchange sites, we hold all posts to a high quality standard. The inclusionist argument of "we're just having fun!" wouldn't hold on any other Stack Exchange site, and we're no different in that regard.

Comment: There's even an API now - left-pad.io

Comment: @Sklivvz As an early mod here, I carry a lot of the responsibility for setting the "we discourage language-specific challenges" tone in the community. (See [this thread](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235/3), for example.) I still believe this question could be multi-language and still fun, IMHO. :-) (BTW, I saw your IRC messages! So feel free to drop by again and chat about this or anything else. I'd love to keep in touch!)

Comment: @m0sa JavaScript is special in that `1 + "1"` is `11`, not, for instance, a `TypeError` (Python) or compiler error (C/C++/etc). Should our answers work for `f("foo", 5, 0)` to give `00foo`, or may we assume the first and last arguments will *always* be strings?

Comment: I'm not surprised this challenge showed up so soon - I was thinking of posting a similar one myself. :)

Comment: Why is there a reopen vote? As @edc65 said, it doesn't have a spec.

Comment: Here is a spec because people wanted a spec.

Comment: I was wrong, 2 lines of text give a complete spec. Voting to reopen. Note: many current answers don't fulfill *this* spec

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Would you mind adding a test case with the new spec :p.

Comment: Added the new test case.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Shouldn't it be `abaa`?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy In the original test cases, *padstring* can be a number. Also, the referenced npm package isn't supposed to take a *string*, just a single character. `leftpad('a', 4, 'ab')` returns something nonsensical.

Comment: @AandN `a̶b` `ab` `a`

Comment: @Dennis True and true. but if we're not restricting to JS, then _padstring_ being a number makes less sense (and makes it impossible in strongly typed languages like Java)

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I don't fully understand the last test case. I think you need to elaborate a bit more on that in the challenge spec.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I'm not saying it's a *bad* change, but the test cases would have to get amended to reflect the change. Also, I disagree with changing the spec from *pad char* to *pad string*, as it break many existing answers.

Comment: @AandN Is that better?

Comment: @Dennis Well the community will decide if the changes are good. _how did I get into this mess_

Comment: Specification, test cases and the linked code on GitHub all contradict each other. I'm re-closing this until everything get cleared up.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy It's poor taste to edit a challenge and invalidate the majority of the many existing answers, *especially* when the challenge isn't even your own.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy why can't the last test case also give `"abaa"`? no explanation of this, and breaks nearly every answer.

Comment: I disagree with replacing `===` with `>`, but the original spec didn't say anything about strings vs characters, so I guess that's OK

Comment: also, I don't know why the link to the github test repo was edited out, as it was clearly _part of the problem_. The first and last parameter, as specified by the tests on github, is anything the language can turn into a string; e.g. in C# this should be `object`...

Comment: and for reference, here's the link to the tests on github, as it was edited out https://github.com/azer/left-pad/blob/76979f0a50877c50afd817923acf6f224bba3d36/test.js

Answer (score 21):

### Pyth, <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
+*.xwd-Qlzz
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2a.xwd-Qlzz&input=foo%0A5&debug=0).

Takes input from STDIN as the string on the first line, length on the second line, and padding char optionally on a third line.

Comment: This is suppose to be javascript only

Comment: @MMM Language restrictions in challenges are so universally disliked that I expect it to be summarily ignored. Nobody likes to be told "*you* can't participate."

Comment: @MMM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_disobedience

Comment: Stick it to the man! You go Doorknob! Don't let your dreams be dreams! JUST DO IT!

Comment: 'Tis a wicked society where the moderators are the one doing civil disobedience!

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That's longer because of the need for conditional application (see the first revision).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I think it pads to the nearest multiple of the input number which is not suitable for this case.

Comment: This got flagged as low-quality. Coincidence? :P

Comment: Note that this code was broken by a recent update to Pyth, but worked at the time.

Answer (score 14):

### JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

```
f=(s,n,p=" ",r=p)=>(r+=s+="")[n]?s:f(r,n,p)
```

Comment: you're missing the 3rd parameter

Comment: @m0sa Thanks, fixed.

Comment: It fails the third test, now ;-)

Comment: @Sklivvz Ugh, that's what I get for not reading the requirements properly.

Comment: Instead of ```p+=s```, you can add 2 bytes to make it ```p+=[s]```, and it'll work.

Comment: @Aplet123 Thanks for pointing out that I'd tried (and failed, as it happens) to fix the fourth case, rather than the third. Sadly it cost me a fair number of bytes to fix them both.

Comment: **If** we use the new spec by @CatsAreFluffy, this is ok for `'foo',5,'.-'` but curiosly fails for `'foo',6,'.-'`  (or any even padding len)

Comment: @edc65 It's not that curious, it assumes that `\`${p}\`.length == 1`

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy What's the expected result for `'foo',6,'.-'`?

Comment: It's curios because I was expecting a more blatant fail (see Pyth answer). Instead it's just a char too long and just for even length.

Comment: @edc65 That doesn't help; I can't seem to run the Pyth answer at all.

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript ES6, 35 bytes

```
(s,l,c=' ')=>c.repeat(l-s.length)+s
```

[Try it.](https://jsfiddle.net/ff41ht4c/2/) I believe this is the shortest possible implimentation currently possible in Javascript.

Comment: This is what I was going to do, except it wasn't an anonymous function.

Comment: @Aplet123 I think by the contest's definition of what's expected this is ok. It was just asking for the function; naming it is irrelevant in this context or at least that's what I would think based on other answers.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <strike>37</strike> <strike>43</strike> 44 bytes

```
(a,n,c=' ')=>((c+'').repeat(n)+a).substr(-n)
```

Test:

```
> f=(a,n,c)=>((c?c:" ").repeat(n)+a).substr(-n)
< function (a,n,c)=>((c?c:" ").repeat(n)+a).substr(-n)
> f('foo', 5) === '  foo';
< true
> f('foobar', 6) === 'foobar';
< true
> f(1, 2, 0) === '01';
< true
> f(1, 2, '-') === '-1';
< true
```

Not sure if you want to count the function declaration, I'd inline this.

Comment: I think that generally, we don't count the function declaration unless the question specifically asks for a full program rather than a function.

Comment: `slice` is shorter than `substr`.

Comment: @Deusovi right. what I mean is that I wouldn't do `console.log(f("whatever",10, "*"))`, but `console.log(("*".repeat(10)+"whatever").substr(-10))`

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, <s>33</s> <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
lambda a,b,x=" ":a.rjust(b,x)
```

<s>Fairly straightforward.</s> Thanks to [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for reminding me `str.rjust` is a thing. :P

For the same length (also thanks to xnor):

```
lambda a,b,x=" ":(x*b+a)[-b:]
```

Previous solution:

```
lambda a,b,x=" ":x*(b-len(a))+a
```

Comment: It's a bit shorter to do `(x*b+a)[-b:]` or `a.rjust(b,x)`. Actually, `str.rjust` itself arguably works for the whole thing.

Comment: @xnor I forgot `rjust` was a builtin, thank you!

Comment: None of these follow the spec: `f(1, 2, 0) === '01';`

Comment: @ValentinLorentz I asked the OP for clarification on languages that don't coerce numbers to strings by default, and haven't gotten an answer. As this question has no formal specification, I'm going to assume the arguments are all strings.

Comment: Now there's a spec, and solution 1 is invalid (tested on Python 2.7.10)

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Okay, well, 1) the question's closed so I see no reason to update (if it were reopened, then...), 2) why would you test a Python 3 submission in Python 2? Even if the behaviour seems the same, that's still silly.

Comment: Doesn't work in Python 3 either.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy cool, it was your edit that invalidated almost every (or every) answer and made this less fun, so I'm not bothered

Comment: You don't need a lambda. `str.rjust` is a valid answer (as `str.rjust` is just as much of a valid function expression as a lambda)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

Code:

```
g-ð³0@×¹«
```

Explanation:

```
g          # Implicit first input, take the length.
 -         # Substract the length with the second input.
  ð³       # Push a space and if the third input exists, also the third input.         
    0@     # Reposition the first element of the stack to the top (zero-indexed).
      ×    # Multiply the character with the difference in length.
       ¹«  # Concatenate the first input to the string.
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Zy3DsMKzMEDDl8K5wqs&input=Zm9vCjUKLQ).

Comment: All these chars fit into the Jelly codepage (0x672D188330401181FA)

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES5), 70 bytes

Using recursion...

```
function f(s,c,p,u){return(s+'').length<c?f((p==u?' ':p+'')+s,c,p):s}
```

My initial go was only 57 bytes:

```js
function f(s,c,p){return s.length<c?f((p||" ")+s,c,p):s}
```

But only passed the first 2 tests:

```js
> f('foo', 5) === '  foo';
true
> f('foobar', 6) === 'foobar';
true
> f(1, 2, 0) === '01';
false
> f(1, 2, '-') === '-1';
false
```

I still like the shorter one, because in practise, passing numbers to a string manipulation function isn't a feature I would need.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
StringPadLeft
```

Builtin-only answer #3 (first was `Range`, second was `Surd`)
Or less builtin: (35 bytes)

```
##2~StringRepeat~(#3-Length@#2)<>#&
```

Comment: May I quietly downvote?

Comment: ...Why? Is it because this is just a builtin? The 41byte Python answer #1 (which is no longer valid) was just a wrapper for a builtin.

Comment: `It's common practice to disallow built-ins that exactly implement what the challenge asks if that's a concern.` (Appeal to authority: Martin)(but common sense, too)

Comment: @edc65 [Related meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23/34718). I'm pretty sure it's allowed, since built-ins are generally allowed by default. It requires creativity and knowledge on the user's part to know the relevant built-in function.

Comment: @mbomb007 allowed maybe - creative no. I did not flag this answer as invalid but mantain my downvote

Comment: See the answer two above this one-I'm assuming that's been downvoted by you two as well.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript ES7, 16 bytes

```
''.padStart.bind
```

built-ins ftw! Only works on Firefox 48 and above. Valid as this feature was added March 12.

This takes input like:

```
(''.padStart.bind)(arg1)(arg2,arg3)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (ES6), 55 bytes

```
(a,n,c=' ',s=a+'')=>(new Array(++n-s.length).join(c)+s)
```

Create an empty array of values and join version.

```
(a,n,c=' ')=>{a+=''; return new Array(++n-a.length).join(c)+a}
```

Is more readable but the `return` adds a few more characters.

Comment: Since the question is on hold I'm going to put my answer under the JS answer that's most like mine.  43 bytes  (s,n,c=' ')=>(Array(n).join(c)+s).slice(-n)

Comment: Tip: `\`` for `inline code blocks.`.

Comment: `+=` returns the value of its left operand, so the second version becomes shorter: `(a,n,c=' ')=>(new Array(++n-(a+='').length).join(c)+a)` But it becomes longer when you add multichar padding strings.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 4 bytes

```
lpad
```

Passes all the test cases:

```
julia> lpad("foo", 5)
"  foo"

julia> lpad("foobar", 6)
"foobar"

julia> lpad(1, 2, 0)
"01"

julia> lpad(1, 2, '-')
"-1"
```

Comment: Does it work for `rect 7 cor`?

Comment: Yes. `lpad("rect", 7, "cor") => "correct"`

Answer (score 4):

## Bash, 57 Bytes

Parameters: *string width padchar*

```
printf -vX %$2s;Y="${X// /${3- }}$1";echo -n "${Y:${#1}}"
```

Make a string of *width* spaces.

Convert each space character into *padchar*.

Write padding then *string*.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 41 bytes

```py
lambda a,b,x=' ':str(a).rjust(b,str(x))
```

Without the builtin rjust, 43 bytes:

```py
lambda a,b,x=' ':str(x)*int(b/2%3)+str(a)
```

(not what one expects it to do, but it passes the test suite)

Comment: You can remove `s=str` and replace `s` with `str` for same byte count.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
L⁴_ẋ@⁵⁵⁶<?¤³
```

<sup>*So* many variable references. Wasn't Jelly supposed to be a *tacit* language?</sup>

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=TOKBtF_huotA4oG14oG14oG2PD_CpMKz&input=&args=ImFiYyI+Ng+Ii0i)

#### How it works

```
L⁴_ẋ@⁵⁵⁶<?¤³  Main link
              Arguments: string (³), length (⁴), padchar (⁵, defaults to 10)

L             Compute the length of ³.
 ⁴_           Subtract the length from ⁴.
          ¤   Combine the two links to the left into a niladic chain:
     ⁵          Yield ⁵.
      ⁵⁶<?      Yield ⁵ if ⁵ < ⁵, else ⁶.
              Comparing a number with itself gives 0 (falsy), but comparing a
              string / character list with itself gives [0] (truthy).
   ẋ@         Repeat the result to the right as many times as specified in the
              result to the left.
           ³  Print the previous return value and return ³.
```

Comment: `padchar (⁵, defaults to 10)` shouldn't it default to `20` or `32`?

Comment: Superscript 3 to 9 are constants that are initialized to arguments (if present) or some useful default values. The conditional `?` checks if it has its default value 10 and yields a space in that case.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

I used a recursive solution.

```
f=(s,l,c=' ')=>s[l-1]?s:f(c+s,l,c)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, <s>87</s> <s>67</s>  <s>incorrect counted 54</s>, 46 Bytes

```powershell
function f($s,$l,$c=' '){$c*($l-$s.length)+$s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P600L7kkMz9PIU1DpVhHJUdHJdlWXUFds1olWUtDJUdXpVgvJzUvvSRDU1uluPZ/moJSWn6@koIpF4SVlFikpGAG4hgqKRgpKBkoIdi6Sv8B)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf. As this is a code-golf challenge, you need to make an attempt to make your code as short as possible (e.g. by removing whitespace). Also, you might want to add a link to [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfkPBAA) so others can test your code.

Comment: Nice answer! I don't think you have to call your function `left_pad` (looking at the other answers, most of them have called their function `f`)

Comment: I currently count 53 bytes (or 46 by renaming the function to one character). The TIO link is still pointing to an old version, you can do something like [this](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P600L7kkMz9PIU1DpVhHJUdHJdlWXUFds1olWUtDJUdXpVgvJzUvvSRDU1uluPZ/moJSWn6@koIpF4SVlFikpGAG4hgqKRgpKBkoIdi6Sv8B) to make it easier to calculate the bytecount

Comment: Thank for the tips, and thank you for pointing out the incorrect count, I think I got it right this time.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>91</s> 86 bytes

Takes 2 or 3 arguments on the command line. Also uses the rare ["-->" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c)!

*-5 bytes from [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) and [c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)*

```c
l;main(c,v)int**v;{for(l=atoi(v++[2]);l-->strlen(*v);)putchar(c-3?*v[2]:32);puts(*v);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrBDoIwDIDh12kHvcDBhEZ9EMNhaVCW1M2M0Qvx2Svx@n@/0EvEXfkdUwbpDVNuIRgfz1JBr7GVBNZ1j2FGVqLb1qouGYIh42dvssYKQuM92LlM44B81u3vX3dfF9XiF6cf)

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <strike>39</strike> 38 bytes

```lua
s,n,c=...print((c or" "):rep(n-#s)..s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/WCdPJ9lWT0@voCgzr0RDI1khv0hJQUnTqii1QCNPV7lYU0@vWPP///@JScn/zf7rAgA)

Thanks to c-- for saving a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ùVWªS
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=%2bVZXqlM&input=ImZvbyIgNiAiLSI)

```
ù      # left-pad the input string with:
 V     #   second input (length)
  WªS  #   third input, or space if not specified
```

Or, for 1 byte:

```
ù
```

But this isn't a full program, so I don't think it counts. It can be called `AùBC` where A is the string, B is the length, and C is (optionally) the padding character.

Comment: Exactly what I had. If only the underlying JavaScript had default parameters then we could omit the `ªS`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pike](http://pike.lysator.liu.se), 67 bytes

```
mixed n(mixed a,int b,mixed x){return x!=""?x:" "*(b-strlen(a))+a;}
```

*sigh*. The empty string `""` evaluates to `true`. *Why!?*

mixed mixed mixed mixed mixed Pike soup...

Comment: Another language with stupid truthys.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy yeah, Pike is kinda weird, but it has nice string processing utilities.

Answer (score 2):

### [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 12 bytes (noncompeting)

added input node, bugfix on len node, change default results on assign node after the challenge was posted.

```
\ =zzjl-z*j+
```

Explanation:

```
\ =z         - assign default input for `z` to be " " (Will still prompt but no input will return a space instead)
    zj       -     j = input()
      l      -    len(j)
       -     -   eval_or_not_input() - ^
        z*   -  ^*input()
          j+ - ^+j
```

Comment: +1 because answering in the language is helping you refine it :)

Comment: I've edited the format of your header to make it easier to read & easier for userscripts, etc to parse -- roll it back if you disagree.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @muddyfish It seems that every non-Javascript answer here is downvoted.

Comment: @AandN thats just not nice... Also why I couldn't see a pattern from the top 6 answers

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 38 bytes

```
(s,l,c=" ")=>(c.repeat(l)+s).slice(-l)
```

An alternate solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 34 bytes

```arturo
$=>[++repeat ??attr""" "&-size<=&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?ElsxF0)

Arturo has `pad` but here's a non-builtin.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
□ðJ3Ẏ÷ø↳
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJ+IiwiIiwi4pahw7BKM+G6jsO3w7jihrMiLCIiLCIhbGVmdF9wYWRcXCgoLiopXFwpID09PSBcIiguKilcIlxubGVmdF9wYWQoXCJmb29cIiwgNSkgPT09IFwiICBmb29cIlxubGVmdF9wYWQoXCJmb29iYXJcIiwgNikgPT09IFwiZm9vYmFyXCJcbmxlZnRfcGFkKFwiMVwiLCAyLCBcIjBcIikgPT09IFwiMDFcIlxubGVmdF9wYWQoXCIxXCIsIDIsIFwiLVwiKSA9PT0gXCItMVwiIl0=)

Link is to test suite. Somehow, vyncode also gives 8 bytes.

### Explained

```
□ðJ3Ẏ÷ø↳
□ðJ      # append a space to all input arguments
   3Ẏ     # take the first 3 items of that
     ÷    # dump everything to the stack
      ø↳  # call the built-in left pad function.
```

Comment: Because of the new default about taking multiple inputs as a list, [6.75 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJ+ISIsIiIsIjEwMTEwMDAwMDAwMDAxMTEwMTExMTEwMTAwMDEwMDEwMDExMDExMDExMDExMTExMTExMDAxMCIsIiIsIiFsZWZ0X3BhZFxcKCguKilcXCkgPT09IFwiKC4qKVwiXG5sZWZ0X3BhZChbXCJmb29cIiwgNV0pID09PSBcIiAgZm9vXCJcbmxlZnRfcGFkKFtcImZvb2JhclwiLCA2XSkgPT09IFwiZm9vYmFyXCJcbmxlZnRfcGFkKFtcIjFcIiwgMiwgXCIwXCJdKSA9PT0gXCIwMVwiXG5sZWZ0X3BhZChbXCIxXCIsIDIsIFwiLVwiXSkgPT09IFwiLTFcIiJd)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 42 bytes

```
def left_pad(s,t,p=" ");p*(t-s.size)+s;end
```

Parameters: string, size, padchar.

Test suite below; should print all "true"s, just put everything in the same file.

```
puts left_pad("foo", 5) == "  foo"
puts left_pad("foobar", 6) == "foobar"
puts left_pad("1", 2, "0") == "01"
puts left_pad("1", 2, "-") == "-1"
```

Comment: You don't need to use that method name... and you can probably make it a lambda, too. (All the other examples do similar)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>86</s> 88 bytes

This is a function. The third argument is a `varargs` to allow the optional pad char (defaults to `' '`)

```
String p(String s,int l,char...p){return s.length()<l?p((p.length>0?p[0]:' ')+s,l,p):s;}
```

Recursion!
+2 bytes (added brackets because of incompatible type error)

Comment: This TypeErrors. Can always test Ideone (Java 7, but I get the same exact error in Java 8 on my box) http://ideone.com/B7gTA5

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>54</s> 48 bytes

Uses Windows-1252 encoding.

```
function(&$s,$l,$p=~ß){$s=str_pad($s,$l,$p,0);};
```

Run like this (`-d` added for easthetics only):

```
php -r '$f = function(&$s,$l,$p=~ß){$s=str_pad($s,$l,$p,0);}; $s="foo";$f($s,5);echo"$s\n";' 2>/dev/null
```

Old version (without the builtin):

```
function(&$s,$l,$p=~ß){for(;strlen($s)<$l;)$s=$p.$s;};
```

## Tweaks

- Saved 6 bytes by using `str_pad` instead of a loop. Leaving the old one for reference, as builtins are frowned upon

Answer (score 1):

### R, 50 bytes

Late to the party again but here it goes:

```
function(s,n,p=" ")cat(rep(p,n-nchar(s)),s,sep="")
```

This simply prints the output to stdout but does not actually return the padded string (wasn't sure if this is a requirement for the challenge). If this is needed, the solution is slightly longer at 61 bytes:

```
function(s,n,p=" ")paste0(c(rep(p,n-nchar(s)),s),collapse="")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 212 bytes

```
,----------[++++++++++<[<]<+>>[>],----------]<[<]<<<,----------[<[-<++++++++++>]<[->+<]>>>++++++++[-<----->]<++[-<+>],----------]>>[-<<<->>>]++++[>++++++++<-]><<+>,[<->[-<<+>>]]<[->>[-<<<+>>>]<<]<<[->.<]>>>>>[.>]
```

### Explained

```
,----------[      While it isn't a newline
    ++++++++++        Restore the character
    <[<]<+>>[>]       Increment the counter behind the array and return
,----------]      Read and repeat
<[<]<<<           navigate behind the length
,----------[                   While it isn't a newline
    <[-<++++++++++>]<[->+<]>>      x10 the stored number
    >++++++++[-<----->]<++             sub 39
    [-<+>]                         Copy into stored
,----------]                   Read and repeat
>>[-<<<->>>]        Subtract the counter from the target
++++[>++++++++<-]>  Prepare a space
<<+>,[<->[-<<+>>]]  If the next byte isnt eof then we copy it left two and zero the test byte
<[->>[-<<<+>>>]<<]  If the text bit is still high copy space in there instead
<<[->.<]            While the counter is positive write the pad char
>>>>>[.>]           Write the rest of the string
```

Arguments separated by linefeeds. If no pad char is present, a linefeed after the length must still be included.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4xCsNQDEP3XMVxtm5CFzEe0kKgFBoo9Pw/@i79Tb1ZerJ8fa335/a@PVqbfUzYGAQSRgbzBGTJwDmDcPxyFOI0JMmvJqBQebXY/02VuG66Eln4CEImhM8ht0N6KKvgE7EeQf9I0lKdchZma9u@T5fpAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 110 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func l(n int,c...string)string{q,p:=c[0]," "
if len(c)>1{p=c[1]}
return Repeat(p,n-len(q))+q}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fY5BisIwFIb3OUV4ICSYFisoIugZZLYzgpmQlGD7mqbpbEpPMEeYTRE8hEfxNtNa3amrH_7v8b7_75QW3cVJdZSpprm0SGzuCh9iMHmAcx1MtLrio6uCt5hWQEyNimYMqcUgVBzHI-FjNKVw6436nO0FUCDW0EwjU3ybNK6vk31LvA61R_qhnZaBOYHRcFJyPi3bu_X3Jhk2MU4bsus_B8PgMPk5fCGIXr8QYIoCOH8Glzf4Lf0LPheQgIDZW0whGvh9UteN-Q8)

Uses Go's variadic arguments feature to have an optional argument. Expects at minimum 1 string passed to the function (the string to be padded); the first string after that is the padding character.

A solution were all arguments are explicit is significantly shorter:

#### [Go](https://go.dev), 76 bytes, no variadic arguments

```go
import."strings"
func l(s,c string,n int)string{return Repeat(c,n-len(s))+s}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BzoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK7M3IL8ohI9pbTcEqWlpSVpuhY3fWBixSVFmXnpxUpcaaV5yQo5GsU6yQoQMZ08hcy8Ek0Ip7ootaS0KE8hKLUgNbFEI1knTzcnNU-jWFNTu7gWauYssBEgGzU0Faq5AoD6StI0lBJUyxJi8pR0gIYrpeXnAxlKCkDCVFMTl5KkxCKYKjMcqgxBCgyAhBE-BbpQBVAXLlgAoQE)

Answer (score -3):

## C, 64 bytes

```c
f(s,n,c,p){return memset(p,c,asprintf(&p,"%*s",n,s)-strlen(s));}
```

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/n9zoZ5).

Comment: This does not comply with the specification, as it does not default to space when a character is not provided.

Comment: This code doesn't run as given. `gcc` will let `undefined reference to function printf` pass and include `printf` itself, but no such luck for `memset`, `asprintf`, and `strlen`. You need to add the `#include<string.h>`... etc definitions to make this valid.

Comment: @tac Hmmm...I wrote and tested my answer completely within ideone. It compiles and runs successfully on that platform, though it states that it uses `gcc-5.1`. I'm not sure if they're using compiler flags or what-have-you behind the scenes that I'm not aware of. I was initially using [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5851/are-compiler-specific-submissions-allowed) as my justification for it not running in your environment, but now I'm not sure...

Comment: well, this is `gcc 5.2.1` on Linux, so you might be able to get away with saying `Ideone C, 64 bytes` but if you're gonna claim it's C, make it compile. :p

Comment: I'm only a beginner at C: Why does `f` take four parameters, not 3? Are you requiring the address of the string, or...? either way, `f` should take at most 3 arguments.

Comment: I hadn't previously tested this. http://ideone.com/H2t6DR It works with three args!  However, it doesn't coerce ints to strings. http://ideone.com/i2fzRZ

Comment: @Doorknob Consider deleting this as it doesn't meet the requirements?