# Longest run of a character in a string

Tags: code-golf, string

Your challenge: Write a function that takes a string `s`, a character `c`, and finds the length of the longest run of `c` in `s`. The length of the run will be `l`.

**Rules**:

- If `s` is of length 0 or `c` is empty, `l` should be 0.
- If there are no instances of `c` in `s`, `l` should be 0.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/61563) and [Standard I/O Rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/61563) apply.
- No matter where in `s` the run of `c`s is located, `l` should be the same.
- Any printable ASCII characters can appear in `s` and `c`.

**Test cases**:

```
s,c --> l
"Hello, World!",'l'  -->  2
"Foobar",'o'         -->  2
"abcdef",'e'         -->  1
"three   spaces",' ' -->  3
"xxx xxxx xx",'x'    -->  4
"xxxx xx xxx",'x'    -->  4
"",'a'               -->  0
"anything",''        -->  0
```

**Winner**:

As with [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55880/61563) [Sandbox post.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12767/61563)

Comment: Could you include the edge cases of empty `s` and a `c` that isn't contained in a non-empty `s` in your test cases?

Comment: What range of characters can appear in `s`/`c`?

Comment: @MartinEnder Clarified both.

Comment: `c` can be empty? In many languages, a character is just an integer with special semantics, and you can't really have an empty integer either.

Comment: @MartinEnder I didn't explicitly state that `c` *can* be empty, I just stated that if it (somehow) *is* then `l` must be 0.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. Your test cases suggest that we have to support it. If we don't have to support it, then specifying its required output doesn't make sense, because I can always just say that it's not supported if my solution would do something else in that case.

Comment: Any ASCII or any printable ASCII?

Comment: @jpmc26 Printable ASCII; updating.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

#### Code:

```
SQγOM
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/OPDcZn/f//89UnNy8nUUwvOLclIUuXIA)

#### Explanation:

```
SQ      # Check for each character if it is equal to the second input
  γ     # Split the list of zeros and ones into groups
   O    # Sum each array in the arrays
    M   # Get the maximum
```

Comment: Nice solution! I knew there was a way to do it like this, I just couldn't think of it.

Comment: `γ¢M` isn't performing like I thought it would, thought that'd be a 3-byte.

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
Max[Tr/@Split@Boole@Thread[#==#2]]&
```

Pure function taking a list of characters and another character as input and returning a nonnegative integer. Improved upon my first effort using [Adnan's observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125385/56178) (go upvote!) that one should test for equaling the special character before splitting the array.

`Thread[#==#2]` checks whether each input character in the first argument equals the character given as the second argument. `Boole` converts the resulting `True`s and `False`s to `1`s and `0`s. `Split` splits the list into runs of consecutive elements; `Tr/@` sums each sublist, and `Max` finds the winner. (Because of how `Max` works, if the first argument is the empty list, then this function returns `-∞`. So, you know, don't do that.)

### first submission (51 bytes)

```
Max[Split@#/.a:{c_String..}:>Boole[c==#2]Length@a]&
```

`Split@#` splits the input into runs of consecutive characters, such as `{{"t"}, {"h"}, {"r"}, {"e", "e"}, {" ", " ", " "}, {"s"}, {"p"}, {"a"}, {"c"}, {"e"}, {"s"}}` for the fourth test case. `/.a:{c_String..}:>` replaces each subexpression `a` that is a list of a repeated character `c` by `Length@a` multiplied by `Boole[c==#2]`, which is `1` if `c` equals the input character and `0` otherwise. Then `Max` extracts the answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>20 18</strike> 15 bytes

```
fV+Vî+)ª0)n o l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/Py1MO@zwOm3NQ6sMNPMU8hVy/v9XKskoSk1VUFAoLkhMTi1W0lFXUAcA)

Saved 5 bytes thanks to obarakon and ETHproductions

Comment: I played around with my own solution for a while and ended up with one that was nearly yours, but shorter. If you use `fV+Vî+)`... I'll let you figure the rest out :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions `"If s is of length 0 or c is empty, l should be 0"`, I might be taking that too literally though

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized that fails whenever `s` does not contain any instances of `c`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,c:+(c in s)and-~f(s,c+c[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxCsIwEIDhuX2Ks0sbGkEdC13FN3AQhzS50kBMQhIxLr56vFqXO/6P4/w7Lc6eSplHIx6TEhC5HPpOgrYQmbBq/5k7sl7eDndWXos2CMehrshGbf0zdayufNA2we@QcXoBsjQXNMZxuLpg1K7hrWnr5uzcJAKFoxCTVDhTIEVaAiIARC8kRkIgzDlD3gZJ3mStVf9CS7Rf)

Dennis saved 3 bytes by updating `c` to a string of duplicated characters rather than recursively updating a number to multiply `c` by.

Comment: `f=lambda s,c:c in s and-~f(s,c+c[0])` saves 6 bytes (3 if *False* is not allowed).

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 6 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [carusocomputing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/carusocomputing)

```
γvy²¢M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OayykNrDm0KzEyvNfD9/78koyg1VUFBobggMTm1mEsBAA)

```
γ      # split into chunks of consecutive equal elements
 vy    # For each chunk...
   ²¢  #  Count the number of input characters in this chunk
     M #  Push the largest count so far
```

Comment: `γvy²¢M` for 6-bytes, same idea.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
=ĠṠG
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI9xKDhuaBHIiwiIiwiW1wieFwiLFwieFwiLFwieFwiLFwiIFwiLFwieFwiLFwieFwiLFwiIFwiLFwieFwiLFwieFwiLFwieFwiXVxueCJd)

```
=    # Is each character of the string equal to the character?
     # Produces a list of 1s and 0s
 Ġ   # Group consecutive items
  Ṡ  # Sum each - groups of 1s become their length, groups of 0 become 0 
   G # Find the maximum
```

Comment: [9 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B%E2%81%B0%3D%3B%C4%A0%C6%9B%E2%88%91%3BG&inputs=xx%20xxxxx%20xxxx%20x%0Ax&header=&footer=), also later I got it down to 6 bytes, but I decided to post myself, +1 too you too

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Neil*
*-1 byte thanks to @apsillers*

```js
s=>c=>[...s].map(x=>j=(i=x==c&&i+1)>j?i:j,i=j=0)&&j
```

Takes input in currying syntax: `f("foobar")("o")`.

### Test Snippet

```js
f=
s=>c=>[...s].map(x=>j=(i=x==c&&i+1)>j?i:j,i=j=0)&&j
```

```html
String: <input id=I> Letter: <input id=J maxlength=1 size=1> <button onclick='O.innerHTML+=`f("${I.value}")("${J.value}") = ${f(I.value)(J.value)}\n`'>Run</button><pre id="O"></pre>
```

#### Another option using `eval` and `for` (54 bytes)

```js
s=>c=>eval("i=j=0;for(x of s)i=x==c&&i+1,i>j?j=i:0;j")
```

#### Old Answer using Regex (85 bytes)

```js
s=>c=>c?Math.max(...s.match(eval(`/${/\w/.test(c)?c:"\\"+c}*/g`)).map(x=>x.length)):0
```

Comment: I think `x==c?i++:i=0` can just be `i=x==c&&i+1` since a `false` result on `x==c` comparison will be treated as a `0` for numerical comparisons and increments (and will never be the return value, since any number, including `0`, in `j` will always take priority over the zero-like `false` in `i`)

Comment: @apsillers Thanks, updated, but what do you mean about it never being the return value?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I was just explaining that the change would never make your program return `false` (since the challenge always requires it to return a number)

Comment: `s=>c=>[...s].map(x=>j=(x!=c?i=0:++i)>j?i:j,i=j=0)&&j` seems to save a couple of bytes.

Comment: @Neil Nice, thanks, that's one more byte off

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong code, I meant to post `f=s=>c=>[...s].map(x=>j=(i=x==c&&i+1)>j?i:j,i=j=0)&&j`, which is a byte shorter.

Comment: @Neil Updated. One less than apsillers now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## C# <s>116</s> 115 bytes

My first code golf

Edited because initial submission was a snippet and was missing required namespace for regex

Edit#2 complete rewrite to support characters with special regex meanings

<s>using System.Linq;s=>c=>System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s,"[^"+c+"]",++c+"").Split(c).Max(x=>x.Length);</s>

```
using System.Linq;s=>c=>{var r=(char)(c-1);return string.Join("",s.Select(x=>x==c?c:r)).Split(r).Max(x=>x.Length)};
```

Comment: I don't know C# but it looks like your code expects variables `c` and `s` to be predefined.  We call this a "code-snippet" and it is not allowed.  You could probably restructure your code as an anonymous function or to set those variables to input.  Both of which are allowed.

Comment: Does that work? (See above edit)

Comment: Once again I don't know C#, but it looks like it does.  You might want to checkout our [tag:tips] for golfing in C# [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c) for more experienced advice in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I will definitely peruse the C# tips

Comment: Hi just some general comments for golfing in C#, you can define your function as `(s,c)=>`. You have to either use  `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` or add an using statement right before your function.

Comment: Building off of Stefan's comment your using Linq so you must include `using System.Linq;` into your byte count. When compiling to an anonymous function you can also save bytes by using currying i.e. `s=>c=>...`

Comment: Do I also need using System.Collections.Generic if I am using Lists? Asking for another entry I submitted to another question.

Comment: Also, thank you for introducing me to currying. This is exactly why I wanted to start doing these, it's only my first post and already I'm learning new things I'd never heard of before.

Comment: Does this also work for `c=']'`?

Comment: [Here is a collection of C# golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c)!

Comment: @RomanGräf No, it does not,and now that you pointed out that bug I see a few more. Looks like I've got a rewrite to work on.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>43</s> 39 bytes

```
f c=maximum.scanl(\n k->sum[n+1|c==k])0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h2TY3sSIztzRXrzg5MS9HIyZPIVvXrrg0NzpP27Am2dY2O1bT4H9uYmaegq1CSj6XgkJBUWZeiYKKQpqCerK6glJycrJCMoRQwpTFIpSYlJySmqb0HwA)

Run through the string and replace the current char with a counter that is increased whenever it equals `c` or reset to `0` if not. Take the maximum of the list.

Thanks to @xnor for 4 bytes.

Comment: You can do `sum[n+1|c==k]`.

Comment: @xnor: Nice! I've experimented with `*fromEnum(c==k)`, both pointfree and lambda, but it was always 2 or 3 bytes longer.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), <s>75</s> 72 bytes

```
(s,c)=>Math.max(0,...(for(s of s.split(/((.)\2*)/))if(s[0]==c)s.length))
```

ES6 compatible snippet:

```js
f=
(s,c)=>Math.max(0,...s.split(/((.)\2*)/).filter(s=>s[0]==c).map(s=>s.length))
```

```html
<div oninput=o.textContent=f(s.value,c.value)><input id=s><input id=c maxlength=1 size=1><pre id=o>0
```

`split` returns a bunch of empty strings and single characters as well as the runs but this doesn't affect the result.

Answer (score 3):

## [Micro](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Micro), 112 bytes

```
{T l m 1+:Q # T Q T l~:r}:Z{T[0]+}:X
{i s m:n
n p = if(Z,X)
i L=if(,a)}:a
0\\:C:s:i"":p"":n[0]:T
s l:L
a
T l m:\
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 70 bytes

```php
for(;~$c=$argv[1][$i++];)$r[]=$argv[2]==$c?++$n:$n=0;echo$r?max($r):0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcqxCsMgEADQvZ8hB0kwgbRjrqcfIg4i0etQlRtCp/51ZgOl6@M1bv1pG7cbBMkHObWoWaWUsxhjMrOahzB47KnKiF@I9Hvu7h28tPY4gTj/x4cngmi1hrJBoRX3yBXEvsNnBJm2FXs/S11iiLxf)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 75 bytes

```php
for(;~$s=substr($argv[1],$i++);)$r[]=strspn($s,$argv[2]);echo max($r?:[0]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYqxCsIwEEB3v6KEgyY0BXU0hn5IyBBDNQ42x53KTf61cyx2ecN7Dwu284QFd5Do9vZBjcoqEelkg7K99NG1ayXtPsCeXxd@kv7v4RAt3IfBOAMUol8D46KB7ZaP0bg5l9o9kmig6RT2q2ntu9Qxp1zmHw)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 83 bytes

```php
<?=@preg_match_all("<".preg_quote($argv[2])."+>",$argv[1],$t)?strlen(max($t[0])):0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLDoMgFAX3foW5kggpPuqyIvY/KDHEEFmgUkub@@NdW2PPbiaZE1zYRR9cSIjZpk@noAAOiJhmWVWhPIb4EAJTROC5zHWb9PJIunvY7DTMJo5uMN5TEFCe6vleo6XnnWo0K@Eigf/xqjmJrH/FzduFzgYpiarWjN3qdt@/y1qMZnT2Bw)

+8 Bytes to avoid `@`

```php
<?=($a=$argv[2])&&preg_match_all("<".preg_quote($a)."+>",$argv[1],$t)?strlen(max($t[0])):0;
```

Comment: The 67 bytes version will fail for any regex special char (and `#` of course).

Comment: ... and `~` may fail for `chr(207)`.

Comment: @Titus Done and Input can only be Ascii characters

Comment: good eye for `++$n`! You meant printable ascii. ;)

Comment: `echo$r?max($r):0;` saves one byte

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
f⁴L
ŒgÇ€Ṁ
```

Explanation:

```
f⁴L
f⁴      -Filter by the character argument.
  L     -Return Length of filtered String.

ŒgÇ€»/
Œg      -Group string by runs of characters.
  Ç€    -Run above function on each group.
    Ṁ   -Return the largest in the list.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/tUeMWH66jk9IPtz9qWvNwZ8P///8zgFL5CuX5RTkpiv9zAA)

Comment: You can save a couple of bytes with `Œgf€L€Ṁ`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 63 bytes

```c
i;m;f(s,c)char*s;{for(i=m=0;*s;s++)*s^c?m=m>i?m:i,i=0:i++;s=m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BisIwEIbvPsVspLSxKXg2RE@77H2FvZSFOKY60DSSeAiIz16netniHAb@7xtmBpsT4jiS9rqrkkKJZxtXSd@6ECsy3qw1p1TXcpX@cOeN39LOb0iRWW@ornUyXt/H5dF1NDjYf/7sn2vgEmm4dpVoRZFaoaAssISm2QIU1A4MkgJU8DoqF97SUMnbArieS8S36/ug4DfE/vghVNmXUv/TXyEcbGQe5twekH9h7ub8eo7OcUoXiy6xh7nPOUN@NZb5TU5iGniXTOxE7uMD)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>45 43</s>  42 bytes

```perl6
->$_,$c {$c&&$_??.comb(/$c+/)».chars.max!!0}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZY9da8IwFIbv8yuOpdgWk7ovvFhRt4uOwTa92NgYFCRNj1OoTWnqqDh/2e72x7pTde4rgZC8z3vOe5JjkfbqpUF47fkqYIsVtJVOEPq1GNgTbitY26rdtifDoa/0Ina7tup0vY93X81kYfyFrFqto01NhRclmhL6kM4zNK5HKD@HNQNo2t@NRzfhs7gPQzEai/Dx8jYg8tZcXN8sY1O6jhADh9P2PA72hG1YU/hATQOWpzKDzjYhYFNd7MPEANzI8EjxCKscVYkJjxI0ytsGzw00n3ENV9Ty4IDGwTa1dY1pqjk86SJNWhZ3UgeAhgA4YdaV1rEsSNQk7tcXk7FKcEoM/7BjZpWzApHeJpcKDXnA2bFTZlVVBdXuIFA5h7qzLWv0hv9jJMjvpB95RzRLtipn8@yFPM5v9gk)

```perl6
->$_,$c {$c&&$_??.comb(/$c+/).max.chars!!0}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZY9da8IwFIbv8yuOpdgW0@o@8GJF3S46Btv0YmNjUJA2PU6hNqWpI6L@9u5EnftKICTv857znpRY5f1mpRA@@oEI2XINbSEzhEHjD@0ptwVsbNFu29PRKBBymbpdW3S6XrBMdCDmSaVard6uobLrGlUNA8gXBSrXGMor2DAA0/xxMr6P3vynKPLHEz96uXkIiWzNxQ3UKlW16/j@0OG0PY@DPWU7ZgqfqWnIyjwpoLNPCNlMVscwfwhurHgseIy6RFFjxuMMlfD2wQsF5iuu4oJanhxgHGzXWHeY55LDq6zyrGVxJ3cAaAiAc2bdSpkmFYmSxOP6YkkqMpwRwz/sjFn1vEKktyoTgYo84BzYBbO01qAPBwHtnOou98zohv9jJCTfST/yejRLsa7ni@KdPM5v9gk)

```perl6
->$_,$c {$c&$_??.comb(/$c+/).max.chars!!0}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZY9da8IwFIbv8yuOpZgW0@o@8GJF3S46Btv0YmNjUJA2PU6hNqWpo6L@9u5EnftKICTv857znhRYZv1mpRE@@r4M2HINbalShEHjDe2psCVsbNm2p6ORL9Uycbq27HRdfxnXvpzHpW61eruGqq4r1BUMIFvkqB1jKK5gwwBM78fJ@D58857C0BtPvPDl5iEgsjUXx9erRFcO97whF7RdV4A9ZTtmCp@pacCKLM6hs08I2EyVxzBvCE6kRSRFhHWBssJURClq6e6DFxrMTxwtJLU8OcA42K6x7jDLlIBXVWZpyxI84wA0BMA5s26VSuKSREXicX2xOJEpzojhH3bGrGpeItJbF7FETR7gB3bBrLquoT4cBGp@qrvcM6Mb/o@REH8n/cjr0Sz5upov8nfy8N/sEw)

### Expanded:

```perl6
-> $_, $c {       # pointy block lambda

    $c & $_       # AND junction of $c and $_
                  #   empty $c would run forever
                  #   empty $_ would return 4 ( "-Inf".chars )

  ??              # if True (neither are empty)

    .comb(/$c+/)  # find all the substrings
    .max          # find the max
    .chars        # get the length

  !!              # if False (either is empty)

    0             # return 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, ES6, 52

Recursive solution that treats the string input as an array (note: the initial input is still a string) and consumes left-to-right in character `C`:

```
f=([C,...s],c,t=0,T=0)=>C?f(s,c,C==c&&++t,t>T?t:T):T
```

Tracks current run in `t` and global best in `T`.

Explanation:

```
f=            // function is stored in `f` (for recursion)
  ([C,...s],  // turn input string in first-char `C` and the rest in `s`
   c,         // argument `c` to search for
   t=0,T=0)   // current total `t`, best total `T`
     =>
        C?             // if there is still any char left in the string
          f(s,c,       // recursively call `f`
            C==c&&++t, // increment `t` if char is match, or set `t` to `false`
            t>T?t:T)   // set global `T` to max of `t` and `T`
          :T           // when string is depleted, return `T`
```

Setting `t` to `false` on non-matches works because whenever `t` is incremented, `false` is treated as `0` (i.e., `false + 1` is `1`), and `false` will never compare grater than any value in global-max `T`.

Comment: Nice solution, I was unfamiliar with the `[C,...s]` syntax.  Should help me `slice()` off bytes from my own posts.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>47</s> <s>40</s> 38 bytes

(Saved 7 bytes thanks to @Neil, and 2 bytes thanks to @HermanLauenstein.)

```
s=>g=c=>c&&s.includes(c)?1+g(c+c[0]):0
```

**Explanation:**

Recursively searches for a longer run until none is found.

**Snippet:**

```js
let f=

s=>g=c=>c&&s.includes(c)?1+g(c+c[0]):0

console.log(f('Hello, World!')('l'  ));  //2
console.log(f('Foobar')('o'         ));  //2
console.log(f('abcdef')('e'         ));  //1
console.log(f('three   spaces')(' ' ));  //3
console.log(f('xxx xxxx xx')('x'    ));  //4
console.log(f('xxxx xx xxx')('x'    ));  //4
console.log(f('')('a'               ));  //0
console.log(f('anything')(''        ));  //0
```

Comment: So simple! Brilliant!

Comment: Can you not do `f=(s,c)=>c&&s.includes(c)&&1+f(s,c+c[0])`?

Comment: Or better still, curry it to `s=>g=c=>c&&s.includes(c)&&1+g(c+c[0])`.

Comment: That almost works, but it returns "false" and a null string for the last two cases.  That's fixed by appending `||0`, which is still shorter than my solution.

Comment: The `f=` isn't part of the curried version, because only the inner function is recursive.

Comment: Sweet.  I post so many recursive answers, this technique should really help out.

Comment: `f=s=>g=c=>c&&s.includes(c)?1+g(c+c[0]):0` is 2 bytes shorter

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
=ŒgṀS
```

This is a dyadic link/function that takes a string and a character. Note that it cannot work as a full program, as input from command-line arguments uses Python syntax, and Python – unlike Jelly – does not distinguish singleton strings from characters.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc2xCsIwEAbg3af43YM@gau4FxTHa3u1lWBKWiXdio/grLOLo6DiKD5I@yKxqQEd7nJ8P5dbs5SVtZP3YdU86sA2zyvm7f6C13nsniXQ3G9tfUSQy6wElZDZhhPmuBDgHUkwRWmPAprjbcS9CBSck6aSEVa/nZG13Wez7qoSWCgt42Fbn0RXctAFU6V0SNqTckRhFHPihZ2UqWYGUOQUceETuMQYA/Ntno1nRy76Zz/TBw)

#### How it works

```
=ŒgṀS  Main link. Left argument: s (string). Right argument: c (character)

=      Compare all characters in s with c, yielding 1 for c and 0 otherwise.
 Œg    Group adjacent, equal Booleans in the resulting array.
   Ṁ   Take the maximum. Note that any array of 1's will be greater than any array
       of 0's, while two arrays of the same Booleans are compared by length.
    S  Take the sum, yielding the length for an array of 1's and 0 otherwise.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 25 bytes

```
(.).*?(\1*)(?!.+\2).*
$.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fQ09TT8teI8ZQS1PDXlFPO8YIyOdS0TP6/z/fLT8/KbEIAA)

The first character is the character to be checked.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>70</s> 67 bytes

three versions:

```php
while(~$c=$argv[1][$i++])$x=max($x,$n=($c==$argv[2])*++$n);echo+$x;
while(~$c=$argv[1][$i++])$x=max($x,$n=$c==$argv[2]?++$n:0);echo+$x;
for(;++$n&&~$c=$argv[1][$i++];)$x=max($x,$n*=$c==$argv[2]);echo+$x;
```

takes input from command line arguments; run with `-r` or [test them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e28c32804921c118e088c07cc97afb6c03f9dde).

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>18</s> 11 bytes

Requires swapping `⊂` with `⊆` in Version 16.0 or having `⎕ML←3` (default on many systems).

```apl
⌈/0,≢¨⊂⍨⎕=⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qr8@jtgnGXI862n3y84AiPR36BjqPOhcdWvGoq@lR7wqgElsg/g9U8F8BDEDquNQ9UnNy8nUUwvOLclIU1bnUc9S5kKXd8vOTEouA4vmo4olJySmpaUDxVFTxkoyi1FQgr7ggMTm1GCivgCpfUVGhUAEhgJIVGJIgCZACTEmgSCKaG/IqSzIy89KBMuoA)

`⎕=⎕` Boolean for equality between two inputs

`⊂⍨` self-partition (begin partitions where a non-zero element is greater than its predecessor)

`≢¨` tally each

`0,` prepend a zero (for the empty-input cases)

`⌈/` max of those

---

Old solution

Prompts first for *s*, then for *c*

```apl
⌈/0,(⎕,¨'+')⎕S 1⊢⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdJz8PSPd06BvoaDzqm6pzaIW6tromkBWsYPioaxGQAVL1XwEMQIq51D1Sc3LydRTC84tyUhTVudRz1LmQpd3y85MSi4Di@ajiiUnJKalpQPFUVPGSjKLUVCCvuCAxObUYKK@AKl9RUaFQASGAkhUYkiAJkAJMSaBIIpob8ipLMjLz0oEy6gA)

`⎕` prompt for s

`⊢` for that

`(`…`)⎕S 1` PCRE **S**earch for the lengths of occurrences of

`'+'` a plus symbol (meaning one or more)

`,¨`  appended to each of the elements of

`⎕` the prompted-for *c*

`0,` prepend a zero (for the empty-input cases)

`⌈/` max of those

*c* must be given as a 1-element vector of an enclosed string if it needs escaping.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,c,m=0,k=0:s and f(s[1:],c,-~m*(s[0]==c),max(m,k))or max(m,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xDoIwFEV3v@LJ0pY8DepG0t0/cGg6FChCaIG0HTAEf71WjC93uOcs982v0E3jLcaWG2WrRoHHGi0vcOBF6UGNDbTUi0spkz@9bZ6gkJzXDK1aqMWBscnBv8c2QdA@QD@CEOSujZkQHpMzzZEgMUQiCKKqutFt4ufO2ZIO9iwZkuUnQ@e0BgA/q1r75IFIWR5gdv0YaLaW19sG65ad06ZVgfrg6HeaYXo53xtj8QM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 66 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
((maximum.(0:).map length).).(.group).filter.elem
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcKxCgIxDADQ3a8It1w7GJyF2xz1I8KRXoNNG9oc@OPOFR8v03hzKXOKWusOD3LCpwy/pC0EpY/oqRhu94hKBoXr4TlixIBHb6dFTFKcO3JhnUpSYQPrUh1CgnWssLxkjH8zWeL81nbdac/8Aw)

A slightly easier to read version - not pointfree:

```hs
f c s = maximum (0:(map length (filter (elem c) (group s))))
```

Groups the string by letter, then filters by those groups that contain the right character, then finds the lengths, appends 0 to the list of lengths in case it doesn't appear, and finally finds the maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 109 bytes

```
(s=Differences[First/@StringPosition[#,#2]];k=t=0;Table[If[s[[i]]==1,t++;If[k<t,k=t],t=0],{i,Length@s}];k+1)&
```

**input**

> ["xxx xxxx xx","x"]

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda s,c:c and max(map(len,re.findall(c+'+',s))or[0])or 0
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBbsMgDEDvfIV3IlHRlPVYqdepf9BDhiYHTItEAAEH9vUZbJOy1gfLfs@SZcevcg/@uJnzx@ZwXTRCFuqkAL2GFeuwYhwceZHo1Viv0blBHfiBizyOIc2TbBkmZtcYUoFEW6FcPhVmynCGmUGLmV/IuSDgGpLTL1wAd1yKP/cewoKpw7BDXJQm0yHtsNwTUatyREW5S9hlrRXqb@qmPphOu30yvcV/S337hvW3jrlkkjHTjrNgPexXnX6GY7K@gBls@4AAO7/JcfsG)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
0q~e`f{~@=*}$+W=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/36CwLjUhrbrOwVarVkU73Pb/f/UcBSWP1JycfB2F8PyinBRFJQA)

#### Explanation

```
0                 e# Push 0. We'll need it later.
 q~               e# Read and eval input. Pushes c and s to the stack.
   e`             e# Run-length encode s: turns it into an array of [length, char] pairs.
     f{           e# Map over these pairs using c an extra parameter:
       ~          e#  Dump the pair to the stack.
        @=        e#  Bring c to the top, check equality with the char, pushing 0 or 1.
          *       e#  Multiply the length by the result.
           }      e# (end map)
            $     e# Sort the resulting list in ascending order.
             +    e# Prepend the 0 from before, in case it's empty.
              W=  e# Get the last element.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>66</s> 58 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to BLT and MickyT*

```r
function(s,c)max((r=rle(el(strsplit(s,''))))$l*(r$v==c),0)
```

returns an anonymous function. TIO has a 1-byte difference because `el` doesn't work there for inexplicable reasons.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAe6@oJWg3PNQDvPeDDuEhTEHYMlaLfm/ehpHidfHPZXOIFyZl6dw/RNHCDlOWdHPI9YeBtm02hqjnEaV/tbakJioeYXHMUbVrFD46UMBATe2qHaj8)

Comment: Save a byte with `r=rle(el(strsplit(s,'')))`

Comment: Ignore my previous comment if you saw it.  Got a better one for you `function(s,c)max((r=rle(el(strsplit(s,''))))$l*(r$v==c),0)`

Comment: @BLT `el` doesn't work on TIO (no idea why) and I just copied and pasted it from the working code there so I'll have to remember to put that back in

@MickyT very clever! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 56 bytes

```
{=MAX(IFERROR(FIND(REPT(A2,ROW(A:A)),A1)^0*ROW(A:A),0))}
```

`s` should be input to `A1`.
`c` should be input to `A2`.
Formula must be an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) which adds curly brackets `{ }`.

Technically, this can only handle where the longest run is less than 1,048,576 (which is 2^20) because that's how rows the current Excel will let you have in a worksheet. Since it loads the million+ values into memory whenever it recalculates, this is not a *fast* formula.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
0i0v=dfd1L)0hX>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yDToMw2JS3F0EfTICPC7v9/dY/UnJx8hfD8opwUdS71HHUA)

The basic algorithm is very simple (no use of split!), but I had to throw in `0i0v` and `0h` to allow for the edge cases. Still, I thought the approach was nice, and perhaps I can still find another technique to handle the edge cases: the algorithm finds the longest run in the middle of a string just fine, but not for single characters  or empty strings; I'm still testing if I can 'pad' the variables at better places for better results.

```
0i0v % Prepends and appends a zero to the (implicit) input.
   = % Element-wise equality with the desired char (implicit input)
   d % Pairwise difference. Results in a 1 at the start of a run, and -1 at the end.
   f % Get indices of 1's and -1's.
   d % Difference to get length of the runs (as well as length of non-runs)
 1L) % Only select runs, throw out non-runs. We now have an array of all run lengths.
  0h % 'Find' (`f`) returns empty if no run is found, so append a zero to the previous array.
  X> % Maximum value.
```

Does not work on empty `c`. Then again, I suppose each string contains an infinite run of empty strings between each character :)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>67</s> 65 bytes

```java
s->c->{int t=0,m=0;for(char x:s)m=m>(t=x==c?t+1:0)?m:t;return m;}
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*

Takes input `s` as a `char[]`, and `c` as a `char`

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##pdI9a8MwEAbgPb/imiU2dYS7xrVDKYR26JShQ5pBkeVEqT6MdA4yIb/dlalLJ1NDQQhxd3p4ETrTC12amutz@dkJVRuLcA410qCQpGo0Q2E02QyHbMYkdQ7eqNDXGYBDioLBT/uRnajd7ZPfwnMoUIbcJvCqkR@5LQqoIIfOLQu2LK5CI2CeJipPs8rYqBfAr1ysclVEmPs8Z2u8f1il8VqtMLMcG6tBZbcuCwHCqpuDDBmGKBcjSlAhXrRFK/Rxtwca91EBtq1DrohpkNShhVJHFaF1Ldto/sKlNAm8GyvLuzlB0wd/spa2URwPQwu5iOPsT2pjzIHaMcNMMuiBlbwaM/gkA0@W8zDjasq4G7NgkuW9B/@9jUF@KtQjPfY/aOw2nfa@usVT@B1jykc6MLfZrfsC)

```java
s->c->{          // Method with char[] and char parameters and int return-type
  int t=0,       //  Temp counter-integer
      m=0;       //  Max integer
  for(char a:s)  //  Loop over the characters of the input
    m=m>(
     t=x==c?     //   If the current character equals the input-character:
      t+1        //    Raise `t` by 1
      :          //   Else:
       0)        //    Reset `t` to 0
    ?m:t;        //   If `t` is now larger than `m`, put `t` as new max into `m`
                 //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return m;      //  Return the resulting max
}                // End of method
```

Comment: `m=m>(t=x==c?t+1:0)?m:t;` is shorter than `{t=x==c?t+1:0;m=m>t?m:t;}`.

Comment: Even though it's wayyyyyy longer, I like my first thought: `s->c->java.util.Arrays.stream(s.split("[^"+c+"]")).mapToInt(z->z.length()).max().orElse(0)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 18 bytes

```sh
tr -c $1 \\n|wc -L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/pEhBN1lBxVAhJiavpjxZQdfn/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBTF/zkA)

Explanation:

- `tr`: `tr`anslate characters in STDIN:

  - `-c`: replace all except
  - `$1`: the first command-line argument
  - `\\n`: with newlines
- `|wc -L`: then output the length of the longest line

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

Takes arguments in swapped order.

```
#1_|':\1,^?
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs1I2jK9Rt4ox1Imz5+JKi9ZRylGyVvJIzcnJt1YIzy/KSVFUigWL5wPF3fLzkxKLoAKpQIHEpOSU1DSogAJQoCSjKDVVQUGhuCAxObUYKlEBlKioqFCogBCooiARkAxUNBEoCmYqgYzPqyzJyMxLV4oFAO41MT0=)

`^?` for each character in `s`, is it not a member of c?
`1,` prepend 1.
`|':\` until the value stops changing, do pairwise *or*. This shrinks each run of 0s by 1 per iteration. Collects all intermediate results.
`1_` Drop the first value (the initial boolean vector).
`#` Length. Counts the number of steps it took to fill the vector with 1s.

If we wouldn't have to deal with empty `c`, this could be 10 bytes instead:

```
#1_&':\0,=
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs1I2jFdTt4ox0LHl4kqLVvJIzcnJt1YIzy/KSVFUslbKUYoFCbvl5yclFgH5+RB+YlJySmoakJ8K4ZdkFKWmKigoFBckJqcWA8UVIOIVFRUKFRACKFgBFwQJgCQQgkBWolIsAKR5KgU=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
=Œg§Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/26KT0Q8sf7mz4f3j5wx2Lav//V6qoUKgAYjCoqFACCigBAA)

-3 bytes thanks to Unrelated String. Port of my Vyxal answer.

This takes a literal character, which can't be input (Jelly treats strings as char arrays), so the footer converts the single-character string into a character. The link can also [be called this way](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/26KT0Q8sf7mz4/6hhTkWFQgUQg0FFxaOGuYeXA4mK/wA).

```
=     # Is each char of the string equal to the given character?
 Œg   # Group consecutive identical items
   §  # Sum each
    Ṁ # Get the maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ṁ¹ẇƤS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsZDOx/uaj@2JPj/4eUOxyY56GtG/v8freQBlM/XUQjPL8pJUVTSUc9Rj9VRiFZyy89PSiwC8vMh/MSk5JTUNCA/FcIvyShKTVVQUCguSExOLQaKK0DEKyoqFCogBFCwAi4IEgBJIASBrESYNEhGAQxgKgA)

Takes a character on the left and the string on the right. Can also take the character as a length-1 string (and thus be run as a full program), but errors if given a length-0 string, so it's unclear if this is valid given input that way due to one of the most confusing comment clarifications in site history.

```
ṁ        Mold the character to the length of the string,
 ¹       then
   Ƥ     for each prefix of that result
  ẇ      test if it's a contiguous substring of the string.
    S    Count up how many are.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 40 bytes

`->s,c{s.split(%r{[^#{c}]}).max&.size||0}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W165YJ7m6WK@4ICezREO1qDo6Trk6uTa2VlMvN7FCTa84syq1psag9n9BaUmxQlq0ukdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqK6joJ6jnrsfwA)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 56 bytes

```
#(apply max(reductions(fn[r c](if(= c %2)(inc r)0))0 %))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 31 bytes

```arturo
$[s c]->size max match s~{|c|+}
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?NXqeeH)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 17 bytes

```
[:>./0(+/;.1)@,e.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxMdrKTk_fQENb31rPUNNBJ1UPIn5zqyZXanJGvoK6R2pOTr6OQnh-UU6KorpCmoJ6jjpUyi0_PymxCCyWDxNLTEpOSU0Di6XCxEoyilJTFRQUigsSk1OLwXIKMLmKigqFCggBlqhAkgAJgiRRJcC8RLh9eZUlGZl56WBRdYjjFyyA0AA)

```
[:>./0(+/;.1)@,e.
[:                NB. enforces f(g(y))
     0(+/;.1)@,e. NB. g
               e. NB. check if each char of x is equal to y
     0        ,   NB. prepend a 0
             @    NB. then
      (+/;.1)     NB. cutting and summing
         ;.1      NB. cut up array using first item as delimiter, groups runs of 1's
       +/         NB. sum to get count
  >./             NB. f, get max of result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ôÀV mÊrwT
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9MBWIG3KcndU&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEiCiJsIg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 89 bytes

```lua
s,c=...a=0s:gsub(c:gsub('%W','%%%1')..'+',load'a=math.max(#...,a)')print(#c==0 and 0or a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcvBCoMwDADQX6lISctC6K6D3P0Dz1k75iBaaRX8@2yw0zs9PcWsY2YiEk798e7nM@Q/4GdA8N7fIRLBDVCrFBBe5VholSuMv4YSIe7tsx1hzMzJyVZcqs1JNLPppVrRzbVpGUy/)

Ungolfed version:

```lua
s,c=...                           --Take s and c as program arguments
a=0                               --a stores max run of c
s:gsub(c:gsub('%W','%%%1')..'+',  --For every run of c
load'a=math.max(#...,a)')         --If length of c is longer than a, put into a
print(#c==0 and 0or a)            --If c is 0, print 0, otherwise print a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 98 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY2xCsJAEER7v2KxcRePEC0DJ4itVmIlIpvNXYwkUe6uiIR8ezxNq1MsM7MDzwvXPD7yu5EAB65a6MfCWLAo2e7GTvnsGFzVlqR9Yh91sTc2IKYqJeqFvUEsVEOqI72pLHZaC2GxXKkDh1vScPcNDZGp4zaNbkiu6xHgA2kiD9mVPoOtc/w6T6gLZXBqqwAa@hlEPWMb6hYtLmShYC4iINOZE/2c/Os5l0ievsNsGN8)

```scala
def f(c:Char,s:String)=s.foldLeft((0,0)){case((d,m),x)=>if(x==c)(d+1,Math.max(d+1,m))else(0,m)}._2
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/BSsNAEL3nKx69dBaXED0GIpSeBD2JJxGZTnfbSLqRzQqK5NvjpBukCF6G4b15894bhDuepn735iThgduA7wLYOw9PUmN75Ggx1HhMsQ0HU@MuJDQYSt93@3vnE1FlURlz1gHCgwOR9B8hWZz4cztvxkL0k0Fze74CWg@aITQNxCALcIVrqynSsVTlJfb7yCx6180@1QWjxFi@3hRL/JN2IY4Hzb6Jkb@ec4MXrfAU2rlDDvyuaOoCeVrL2mIlIpA8Vovb35P/cN6JOmd2LMZp@gE)

```scala
object Main {
  def f(c: Char, s: String): Int = s.foldLeft((0, 0)) {
    case ((count, maxCount), char) =>
      if (char == c) (count + 1, Math.max(count + 1, maxCount))
      else (0, maxCount)
  }._2

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(f('c', "ccc cccc cc"))
    println(f('c', ""))
    println(f('c', "abcdef"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `G`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
=ġʂ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSUzRCVDNCVBMSVDQSU4MiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMkglMjIlMkMlMjJlJTIyJTJDJTIybCUyMiUyQyUyMmwlMjIlMkMlMjJvJTIyJTJDJTIyJTJDJTIyJTJDJTIyJTIwJTIyJTJDJTIyVyUyMiUyQyUyMm8lMjIlMkMlMjJyJTIyJTJDJTIybCUyMiUyQyUyMmQlMjIlMkMlMjIhJTIyJTBBbCZmbGFncz1H)

Port of Adnan's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
=ġʂ  # Implicit input
=    # For each character, does it equal the second input?
 ġ   # Group consecutive equal items together
  ʂ  # Sum each inner list
     # Implicit output of maximum
```